# I need to display the number of years that each country has been independent from a column but cannot do so mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When i put in the following into phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT CountryCode, IndepYear, YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(IndepYear, "%Y%"))
from country
where 1
```

I get the following

http://gyazo.com/faea56971dd257691c03ae7f38418c7c (screencap)

and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(IndepYear, "%Y%")) as IndependanceYear or something like that

Comment: Do you need the difference between today date and column IndepYear? What does negative value of IndepYear mean?

Comment: Alex The negative value is the year when the country became independent, and i need the difference of our current year and indepyear

Comment: @John Whittle So what's the difference between negative and positive values?

Comment: Alex i'm not even sure, this has been racking my mind for about a week now

Comment: The negative value is likely BC vs AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had all positive years in the column `IndepYear` the query could be like

```
SELECT CountryCode, IndepYear, YEAR(CURDATE())-IndepYear from country
```

You can find all other date functions in [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).